# Eclipse Marketplace plugins for MyEclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, myeclipse, cloud-foundry, eclipse-marketplace

I'm trying to install the Cloud Foundry plugin using the instructions here:
http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/STS/configuring-STS.html

The problem is that I have MyEclipse 10.0 which doesn't work with Eclipse Marketplace.  Is there any way to get the plugins from Eclipse Marketplace and install them to MyEclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have the normal P2 Installation Manager? If so, you can install the Marketplace client that way. In a normal Eclipse installation, that is *Help -> Install new software*. In the following dialog either select the *Indigo* update site in the combo box, or add http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo yourself if there is none.

When Eclipse has inspected the update site, you will see a list of components available for installation. You should find the Marketplace client under "General purpose tools".

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to thank Bananeweizen for providing the core piece of the answer above. Basically, since MyEclipse 10.5 and earlier does not ship with the Eclipse Marketplace Client pre-installed the first step is to install the client from the: Help > MyEclipse Configuration Center... > Software tab and clicking the '+' icon to add it to the MyEclipse configuration... (if you head over to our blog we have the images there to show you: http://www.genuitec.com/blog/?p=4461)

Next, follow the wizard directions and allow MyEclipse to restart after the installation. Once restarted, you can add items from the Help > Eclipse Marketplace... item as you'd expect.

Now from the Eclipse Marketplace Client you can add whatever software you'd like, like the Cloud Foundry plug-in you asked about.

After the installation and restart, you can add your Cloud server by opening the WTP Java Extras perspective by using Help > Open Perspective... and selecting the "Show all" checkbox...

Then to add your cloud server you can right-click in the WTP Servers view and select 'New > Server'

And select VMWare > Cloud Foundry and follow the steps in the wizard. And that's it.

In closing, since you had to ask the question, it's obvious that we can improve this process a bit, and we will. So that it will be a bit more obvious how to pick up plugins from the Eclipse Marketplace, we'll be adding the Eclipse Marketplace Client to the default configuration of MyEclipse 10.6. I think it will be a nice enhancement for all our users. Thanks for your support of MyEclipse!